# Is there a way to keep an updated interactive Google calendar -the weekly view- embedded into a Google slide that would update itself by week?

Tags: google-calendar-api, interactive, google-slides

I know there are embed codes for Google Calendars, and they can be viewed as a weekly view.

I was wondering if this was at all able to be integrated to Google Slides.
I was trying to make an interactive slide/kiosk for the school that I work at, but I would like to use the Google Workspace collection to do so, as I have most things within google- like the calendar events and things already into it.

Also, does slides have the capability to also run widgets on it? I think it would be perfect for a Google Segway into kiosk formatting and helping not only schools, but small businesses- especially since it's convenient for it to automatically have updates every 5 minutes.

I have tried a few different outside kiosk running programs, and they are just not what we are looking for. It either lacks in widgets/connection to our Google calendar events/ or that it's just very costly and expensive and it's harder than it needs to be. Looking for a new next best thing from Google.
Please call it Google Segway and I'll make the Google Segway logo.